# Invoked method only run once

Tags: java, esper

I have a method that is invoked in the query. However it is only run once, but the listener outputs two null events assuming i send 10 events.

```
select method() from Event.win:length_batch(5)
```

The result from the listener: this is correct since the method dosent return anything, but the method only fires once when it should fire twice.

```
{method()=null}
{method()=null}
```

Does anyone know why? I want the mthod to be run every time the window is filled up with 5 events as you see above the window is filled twice, but my method is only fired once.

Basically I want the method to run multiple times like avg() etc but it is only run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this one in the docs: 16.4.24.3. User-Defined Function or Static Method Cache

*By default Esper caches the result of an user-defined function if the parameter set to that function is empty or all parameters are constant values.*

Comment: I set the udf cahce to false, but now it first fires the method for thw first batch but it prints every batch 5 times for each event. Then when the second batch arrives it merges the last batch with the new batch and prints a total of 10 event lines 5 times(number of events in a batch)

Comment: I think you are looking for using an aggregation method instead or could also just use UpdateListener.